# Ldap configuration and root connection

Tags: ldap, openldap, ldap-client

Mac: Open Ldap

I am new to Open LDAP, i google it and found that max OS comes with default open ldap installed.

I followed this tutorial [MAC Ldap tutorial](http://support.apple.com/en-us/ht4183)

Following is my slapd.conf

```
#######################################################################
# BDB database definitions
#######################################################################

database    bdb
suffix      "dc=my-domain,dc=com"
rootdn      "cn=Manager,dc=my-domain,dc=com"
# Cleartext passwords, especially for the rootdn, should
# be avoid.  See slappasswd(8) and slapd.conf(5) for details.
# Use of strong authentication encouraged.
rootpw      {SSHA}xEYpp/gcd4Mmf6j756LX4kBjSyYyZFz8
# The database directory MUST exist prior to running slapd AND 
# should only be accessible by the slapd and slap tools.
# Mode 700 recommended.
directory   /private/var/db/openldap/openldap-data
# Indices to maintain
index   objectClass eq
```

Now i am using Jxplorere as a client.

I tried following credentials, i don't know what will be user name so i assumed like other apps may be default username is root. and password i used was which i generated.
[image]

when i tried to login got following error.

[image]

any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BaseDN is the suffix, and the username is the rootDN.

Comment: now error msg is changed to  javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: [LDAP: error code 32 - No Such Object]; remaining name 'dc=my-domain,dc=com' any help ?

Comment: You must have mistyped it,m or maybe the '-' needs escaping. NB You shouldn't use the RootDN login for anything.